# Snap-ins Pre-Chat - Case is not created when no "Subject" is given

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel, chat, pre-chat

I use Snap-Ins chat with a Pre-Chat form to connect an external site with Salesforce Service Console which uses Omni-Channel chat.

From the user side:

I fill the prechat form only with first and last name and start a conversation with a service consultant. Only name fields are needed, however email, phone and subject fields are also possible to fill:

[image]

From the Salesforce Side:

My Pre-Chat configuration:

[image]

After accepting the conversation in the Omni Channel window, I can now hold a conversation. Sadly, there is no case assigned to conversation's transcript - after querying newly created cases in a Developer Console it looks like it's not even created at all.

[image]

Whan can be a reason for such a behavior?

I don't even see a way to debug it. `liveagent.enableLogging()` does not work with Snap-Ins code from the client's side. When setting debug logs for a Live Agent User - I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, or set the subject as required or prepopulate the field in the code.

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
            "label": "issue",
            "value": "Subject Case",
            "displayToAgent": true
        }];

    embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
        "entityName": "Contact",
        "showOnCreate": true,
        "linkToEntityName": "Case",
        "linkToEntityField": "ContactId",
        "saveToTranscript": "ContactId",
        "entityFieldMaps": [{
            "isExactMatch": true,
            "fieldName": "Email",
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": true,
            "label": "Email"
        }, {
            "isExactMatch": true,
            "fieldName": "AccountId",
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": true,
            "label": "AccountId"
        }]
    }, {
        "entityName": "Case",
        "showOnCreate": true,
        "saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
        "entityFieldMaps": [{
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "fieldName": "Subject",
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": false,
            "label": "issue"
        }, {
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "fieldName": "Status",
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": false,
            "label": "Status"
        }, {
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "fieldName": "Origin",
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": false,
            "label": "Origin"
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: Hi Manukadi, could you flesh this out at all with some framing to help future askers understand your changes and where to apply them?